# Find the missing number

Tags: number-sequence

What number should replace the **?**
[image]

Comment: For the answer to be correct you need the 21 to be 20

Comment: I expected such a comment. If 21 was 20 then this would be a different puzzle.

Comment: So, the answer is not 15?

Comment: No, it's not 15.

Comment: This puzzle was made by Nob Yoshihagara! I'm not sure what the policy on putting this in the post is, and I didn't want to edit for something this trivial.

Comment: I found it in some puzzle book. You can edit to add the attribution with sources.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

> 12 - (sum of digits) Well I don't like to spoil it entirely for others but here you go(since a moderator asked me to explain more): Add the digits of the two numbers in the circles that branch from a circle just one level above and place the sum in the circle. Eg. Start with 72 and 99 at the bottom, 7+2+9+9=27; put 27 up in there and so on...

And it did tease my brain a little. Thanks ;)

Comment: Thanks @Len . Added more explanation to the spoiler. I just didn't want to spoil it for the curious ones that can't help hover over spoilers while they're just looking for a hint. `:)`